# Jmeter: " &lt; " in dynamic variable

Tags: variables, dynamic, jmeter

New to Jmeter. Still learning. Any help will be appreciated.

Login post request: 
GET https://exe.example.com/dsfs/ls/?wa=esignin1.0&trealm=https%3A%2F%2Fexe.example.com%2F&wctx=rm%3D1%26id%3D82339bbd-7cdb-4372-ae5f-65efd2dac185%26ru%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fexample.com%252fdefault.aspx&wct=2014-05-08T17%3A47%3A46Z&wauth=urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A1.0%3Aam%3Apassword

Above is the post request where I send values for wa, trealm,wctx, wct, wauth which I get from previous response. 
For the above post request I get the below response with one more hidden variable "wresult"

```
<html><head>
<title>Working...</title>
</head>
<body>
<html><head><title>Working...</title></head><body>
<form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://exe.example.com/">
<input type="hidden" name="wa" value="esignin1.0" />

<input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="&lt;t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust&quot;><t:Lifetim….…….../trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType></t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>" /> 

<input type="hidden" name="rctx" value="rm=1&amp;id=f71cbbfb-c9f6-4255-bb38-f9ec81f1d4aa&amp;ru=https%3a%2f%2fexample.com%2fdefault.aspx" />
<noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form><script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script></body></html>
```

I have to send wrestle value in my next request. wrestle value should be like below.

```
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponsexmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust<t:Lifetim……………entity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType></t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

but instead wresult value is being sent as

```
&lt;t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><t:Lifetim….….……entity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType></t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>" />
```

In browser I'm guessing something replaces "`&lt;`" with "<" . I have checked everything, it looks like the request is failing because "`&lt;`" is not getting replaced by 
"<" in jmeter. Is my guess right? If yes, is there a way to edit wresult's value in Jmeter and then send it in the request?

Could anyone please let me know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does not execute any javascript But your Browser does!
So You might be correct!

So, in your analysis, If "<" - only this is causing issues - You can use BeanShell PostProcessor / PreProcessor to look for the char/string to be replaced and replace it with what you want!

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor

Comment: Thanks for understanding my post even though there were errors in the question :) I will try your solution and get back to you. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Content encoding:" "UTF-8" or "iso-8859-1" in your HTTP Request.

Also you have to Check the parameters in "Encode?" column of your request.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the only place where you're experiencing this problem you can work it around by adding a [Beanshell Pre-Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) with the following code:

```
String wresult = vars.get("wresult").replaceAll("&lt;([^.]*?)", "<");
vars.put("wresult",wresult);
```

Add Beanshell Pre Processor with the code above as a child of the request, in where you're trying to pass `wresult` variable.